# Which coefficients are needed to numerically obtain transmission spectrum?

Tags: optics, visible-light, software, optical-materials

I'm using Omnisim program. I would like to obtain transmission spectrum of certain material so I have created two polynomials: one representing real refraction coefficient and one representing imaginary part of refractive coefficient ( $Im(n)=\alpha\lambda/(4\pi)$ ) where $\alpha$ is absorption coefficient.

Do I need something more? I'm asking because my simulations do not obtain spectra with agreement with experimental data.

Comment: Both polynomials are fitted to experimental values

Answer (score 1):

Indices of refraction are really complicated functions and depend quite a lot on all sorts of difficult-to-model molecular properties.

What you really need is to determine over which wavelength *range* you need your approximation to be valid, and then look for experimental data that you can fit to, or models from people who have already done the fitting. http://refractiveindex.info is a good starting point for any search.

For a short range you can probably use a polynomial. For a longer range, you will probably need to model $\epsilon$ using the Sellmeier equation (for a dielectric) or as a coherent sum of oscillators (Drude-Lorentz model.) You can often find Sellmeier coefficients on refractiveindex.info. [This paper, "Optical properties of metallic films for vertical-cavity optoelectronic devices"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1364/AO.37.005271) is an example of the Drude-Lorentz model for several common metals across a fairly long wavelength range.