# Dielectric function for metal, like silver, gold and titanium

Tags: optics, condensed-matter

1. What could be the difference between high reflective metal:Silver and relative low reflective metal:Titanium?
2. Where could I find the data for Fermi screening length, skin depth, and mean free path for such metals?
3. If we consider a thick enough metal film,can lindhard function be applied to such metal?
4. Could you the experts recommend some reference related?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not getting the necessity of [tag:optics] here.

Comment: Dielectric function has correspondence with the refractive index, it's why I tag optics here.

Comment: Ah! okay @Wilson.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which coefficients are needed to numerically obtain transmission spectrum?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/215059/)